# Spaceship operator confusion in PHP7 (return -1)

Tags: php, php-7

I am pretty new to PHP7 and so far it seems great and powerful. I have been using PHP5.6 so I started understanding the usage of spaceship operator `<=>`. But somehow I couldn't get the logic that statement returns `-1`. I know the point of returning to `0` or `1` which are `false` or `true`. Can anyone clarify the usage of `return -1`?

```
Function normal_sort($a, $b) : int 
{ 
  if( $a == $b )
    return 0;
  if( $a < $b )
   return -1;
  return 1;
}

function space_sort($a, $b) : int
{
   return $a <=> $b;
}

$normalArray = [1,34,56,67,98,45];

//Sort the array in asc
usort($normalArray, 'normal_sort');

foreach($normalArray as $k => $v)
{
   echo $k.' => '.$v.'<br>';
}

$spaceArray = [1,34,56,67,98,45];

//Sort it by spaceship operator
usort($spaceArray, 'space_sort');

foreach($spaceArray as $key => $value)
{
   echo $key.' => '.$value.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is <=> (the 'Spaceship' Operator) in PHP 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365346/what-is-the-spaceship-operator-in-php-7)

Comment: This answer on the question I marked answers that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32802797/3000068

Comment: I saw them. My question is not precisely what spaceship operator does. What is the meaning of returning -1?

Comment: @Mr.T Do you mean "what is the meaning?" or "what is the purpose?". The meaning is quite clearly that the first operand is less than the second

Comment: What is the purpose? Sorry i picked a wrong vocabulary. :)

Comment: @Mr.T, in the answer I linked to: "But why would you want such an operator? Again, the RFC addresses this - **it's pretty much entirely to make it more convenient to write comparison functions for usort (and the similar uasort and uksort)**.
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three possibilities when comparing the two values that are passed to a comparison function: `$a < $b`, `$a == $b`, or `$a > $b`. So you need three distinct return values and PHP has chosen the integers: `-1`, `0`, and `1`.  I guess it could just as easily be strings `lesser`, `equal` and `greater` or integers `5`, `7` and `9` or any combination, but it's not.

From the manual [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

- `$a < $b`  return `-1`
- `$a == $b` return  `0`
- `$a > $b`  return  `1`

This is NOT how types work in PHP, but you can think of it like this: is `$a > $b`? where `-1` means `false`, `1` means `true` and `0` means neither (equal).

Comment: I totally understand this. But return -1, return 0, return 1 are returning an integer of -1,0,1 or they are returning to boolean true/false stuff? That is all i wanna understand.

Comment: Thanks for your time.