# sort object by integer key in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, sorting

I have an array with ID's as the key and a name from a database associated with it. I use this to get statistics from PHP for output to a Google Chart generated in JavaScript (through JSON). In PHP I have the following array:

```
$a = [ 
  '33' => 'first',
  '25' => 'second',
  '14' => 'last
];
```

If I run the following code:

```
foreach( $a as $key => $val )
   echo "$key => $val" . PHP_EOL;
```

I get the following (expected) result

```
   33 => first
   25 => second
   14 => last
```

I use AJAX and JSON to send this to a JavaScript environment, here it becomes an object. Now when I run the following JavaScript:

```
for( var i in a )
   console.log( i + " => " + a[i] );
```

I get

```
   14 => last
   25 => second
   33 => first
```

so my keys are interpreted as integers and sorted in JavaScript, which in this case means the array with statistics I was sending to Google Chart is matching up with the wrong labels.

I solved this by sorting the array in PHP before I read the statistics from the database. I needed the keys to stay the same though, this is what I did in PHP:

```
 $tmp = array_flip( $a );
 asort( $tmp );
 $a = array_flip( $tmp );
```

this gives me the array in PHP like this:

```
[
   '14' => 'last',
   '25' => 'second',
   '33' => 'first'
]
```

so now a `foreach` in PHP will have the same order as a `for( i in ...)` in JavaScript. I was wondering if there is either a nicer way of sorting my array in PHP instead of flipping it twice -or- if there's an option for a loop in JavaScript that doesn't order the (admittedly confusing) integer value keys of my array?

Comment: Anyway, wouldn't you prefer making something so that the array isn't sorted on JS side and you can loop through it the way it was supposed to be?

Comment: yes, that's why I posted the whole case here. I was a bit bummed out that PHP's foreach was so different from JavaScripts for( var i in...

Comment: Some browsers implements objects/arrays with key-sorting and there is nothing you can do to change that. You can, however, use an array (with pairs inside) rather than an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)?

> ksort
>
> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7) ksort — Sort an array by key
>
> Description
>
> bool ksort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] ) Sorts
>   an array by key, maintaining key to data correlations. This is useful
>   mainly for associative arrays.

If it doesn't deal well with numeric-strings keys you can use [uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) and write your compare function with a `parseInt` and [spaceship operator (`<=>`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365346/what-is-the-spaceship-operator-in-php-7).

---

If you, however, want to simply stop the reordering fully, altought you can't stop the "sorting" of the object by its keys (and note that it is not standard and is browser-dependent: not all of them will sort it), you can always use pairs inside an array to avoid changes to your original order of elements (pairs, in this case):

`$a = [ 
  ['33', 'first'],
  ['25', 'second'],
  ['14', 'last']
];`

Comment: Nice one. Those pairs are indeed a good way to get around this sorting!

Answer (score 1):

All you need:

```
ksort($a)
```

Result:

```
[
    14 => 'last',
    25 => 'second',
    33 => 'first',
]
```

Comment: that makes a lot more sense...  In one attempt I tried this and killed the index with it (ended up with [0=>'last', 1=>'second', etc).. I tried this again and it worked. I must have done something wrong that first time. Thanks for this answer!