# Sort array of time strings naturally

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, time, natural-sort

I need to sort an array of time strings (which are not zero padded) naturally.

Sample data:

```
$totlahourdat1 = ["9:30", "15:00", "13:00"];
```

When I try `array_multisort($totlahourdat1, SORT_DESC)`, the data appears unchanged.

My actual code:

```
while($row11 = mysqli_fetch_array($hourget))
{
    $totlahourdat1[] = strtotime($row11['hours']); 
}   

array_multisort($totlahourdat1, SORT_DESC);

foreach ($totlahourdat1 as $time) {
    $totlahourdat[] = date("h:i",$time);
}

echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($totlahourdat);
echo "</pre>";
```

Ultimately, the array data should be ordered from earliest time to latest time:

```
["9:30", "13:00", "15:00"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do like below:-

```
$time = array(0=>"9:30",1=>"15:00",2=>"13:00");
function timecompare($a,$b)
{
    return strtotime($a) < strtotime($b) ? -1: 1;
}
uasort($time ,'timecompare');

print_r(array_values($time));
```

Output:-https://eval.in/835353

Comment: This is also good, but @squareCircle's answer requires less computing.

Comment: @localheinz  yes but indexs will may be a slight point of issue:- https://eval.in/835350  (But yes that is really shortest way to do that)

Comment: He only sorted the timestamps  `DESC`, that was the problem with the OP code.

Answer (score 3):

Use `natsort($array)`  [see  function definition](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

Comment: it works but its not changing key values which i need in another loop

Comment: @Harpreet then you can call `array_values()` or just use [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73810873/2943403) ...which is obviously simpler than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `usort()` to write a custom sorting function.

```
$times = array("9:30", "15:00", "13:00");

usort($times, function ($a, $b) {
    $a = strtotime($a);
    $b = strtotime($b);
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

If you are using PHP7, you could use the [spaceship operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365346/what-is-the-spaceship-operator-in-php-7) to greatly reduce the size of the sorting function.

```
$times = array("9:30", "15:00", "13:00");

usort($times, function ($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($b) <=> strtotime($a);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is much simpler than you think. you just forgot to use the proper order

Just Order by `ASC`

```
array_multisort($totlahourdat1, SORT_ASC);
```

See demo here (https://eval.in/835356)

Comment: Why call a "multisort()` function if you are merely doing a "single sort"???

Comment: This answer is provably incorrect. https://3v4l.org/UYZlO

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to parse these time expressions with `strtotime()` or a datetime method.  Just sort naturally.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vpni0))

```
sort($totlahourdat1, SORT_NATURAL);
```