# Changing the order of the array contents by performing arithmetic operations in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array output.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [student_id] => 39
            [scored] => 50
            [out_of] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [student_id] => 40
            [scored] => 80
            [out_of] => 100
        )

)
```

I want to calculate the percentage of the student and want to show the student on top whose percentage is higher. how do i  do it? Can i change the order in the array itself? please help

I want the array to be like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (             
            [student_id] => 40
            [scored] => 80
            [out_of] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [student_id] => 39
            [scored] => 50
            [out_of] => 100
        )

)
```

Comment: usort and a small self-written comparison function, and done. For more details on how to use, see suggested duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your `out_of` is 100 each time means your `scored` itself is percentage

anyways you can use the below code

```
 function sortByScore($x, $y) {
  return $y['per'] - $x['per'];
 }

 $new_arr = array();
 foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
     $per = ($value['scored']  / $value['out_of']  ) * 100;
     $value['per'] = $per;
     $new_arr[] = $value;
 }
```

first calculate the percentage and then sort by percentage

as your `scored` will be more if your `out_of` is different each time , so sorting on `scored` is not feasible

```
 usort($new_arr, 'sortByScore');
 echo "<pre>"; print_r($new_arr);
```

Comment: i tried it. I got the percentages in array but the order of the array did not change. It still shows the record with lesser percentage on top and more percentages record below it.

Comment: this works on php5. I am working on php7 and it dosent work there. But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `usort`

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    // This code will be executed each time two elements will be compared
    // If it returns a positive value, $b is greater then $a
    // If it returns 0, both are equal
    // If negative, $a is greater then $b
    return ($a['scored'] / $a['out_of']) <=> ($b['scored'] / $b['out_of']);
});
```

More details on this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php
A list of all php sort algs: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Be aware that usort will modify the array itself, so DONT use `$array = usort($array, ...)`

Comment: what if the array consist of many more records. This will work for array with only two records right?

Comment: I updated the code with few more comments. The function will be called each time two elements are compared; if you have e.g. "1", "2" and "3" the function will first be called with "1"+"2", then with "1"+"3", then with "1"+"2". So it will work with any array.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think usort works differently on php7. I am using php7 and it does not change the order of the array after performing the operations.

Comment: Well it works like this in my php7-project. Updated the source, try replacing "-" with "<=>" (spaceship operator - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365346/what-is-the-spaceship-operator-in-php-7)