# Sort [key => value] array by another array of keys with same index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of indexes that I want to sort my other array:

```
$order = [7, 2, 1, 4];

$array = [
   1 => "O",
   2 => "T"
   4 => "F"
   7 => "S"
]
```

How can I order the `$array` based on `$order` array, so that the output is..

```
$array = [
   7 => "S",
   2 => "T"
   1 => "O",
   4 => "F"
]
```

*As far as I read, something other than for loop is much preferred*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of [`uksort`](http://www.php.net/uksort) and [`array_search`](http://www.php.net/array_search):

```
uksort($array, static function (int $key1, int $key2) use ($order): int {
    return array_search($key1, $order, true) <=> array_search($key2, $order, true);
});
```

The idea is to sort the array by the positions of its items' keys within the `$order` array:

- `uksort` is a sorting function that allows sorting based on array keys (here 1, 2, 4 and 7),
- `array_search($key1, $order, true)` gives you `$key1`'s position within `$order`,
- `array_search($key2, $order, true)` gives you `$key2`'s position within `$order`,
- `<=>` (known as the [spaceship operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365346/what-is-the-spaceship-operator-in-php-7)) compares these values, so that the sorting puts lower values (aka lower positions within `$order`) first.

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/uK0m7)

Note: performance could be bad if your array is big, as `array_search` will be run several times on the same keys. If that's an issue, what you can do is grab all keys' positions within `$order` first, then sort based on them.

Comment: Please employ the spaceship operator Jeto.  I am using this page to close others.  If you can add a bit more explanation, that would be helpful too.

Comment: @mickmackusa Done. Spaceship operator should be exactly equivalent to `-` here (and I'm wondering if it's got any performance overhead, though probably not), but you're right that it's more common/understandable in the context of a sorting callback.

Comment: Sorry, I had in my mind that modern php versions would complain about the subtraction -- my mistake.