# How to arrange numbers in ascending order in php with if statement?

Tags: php

So I have this:

```
$x=rand(0,100);
$y=rand(0,100);
$z=rand(0,100);
```

How can I put them in increasing order?

Comment: Add those number to an array, then sort the array using `asort()`

Comment: `$x=rand(0,33); $y=rand(34,66); $z=rand(67,100);` should work.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that doesn't guarantee the same result though. You can't get  `x=1` `y=2` `z=3`

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)];
sort($array);
list($x, $y, $z) = $array;
```

Answer (score 0):

As your questions reads like a homework I'll show you some code that generates the expected result but won't be a valid due.

```
$x = rand(0,100);
$y = rand(0,100);
$z = rand(0,100);

$numbers = [$x, $y, $z];

usort($numbers, function($left, $right) {
    return $left <=> $right;
});

array_walk($numbers, function($val) {
    echo $val . PHP_EOL;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PHP7, they introduced the Spaceship Operator which could be useful for you.

[What is <=> (the 'Spaceship' Operator) in PHP 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365346/what-is-the-spaceship-operator-in-php-7)

Update: There is actually a much easier answer than that. Put them in an array and use `sort()` on the array; http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php