# Sort json results from "complex" API in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a problem I can't solve. I ask an API to get fields in a select box and everything works well... but I would like to have them sorted alphabetical.

I looked on `usort` function but it doesn't work because of the json architecture I think. I need more knowledge to know how to do that and I can't find that answer. Thanks a lot.

```
$urlsta = "https://hubeau.eaufrance.fr/api/v1/hydrometrie/referentiel/stations?code_departement=71&en_service=true&format=json&size=50";
$raw = file_get_contents($urlsta);
$json = json_decode($raw,true);
usort($json['data'], function($a, $b) { return $a->libelle_commune > $b->libelle_commune ? -1 : 1; });                                                            
foreach($json['data'] as $ligne) {
  echo "<option value='".$ligne['code_station']."' ";
  echo ">".$ligne['libelle_commune']." - ".$ligne['libelle_cours_eau']."</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my guess. **json['data']** is a array so you dont use **$a->libelle_commune**

My code

```
usort($json['data'], function($a, $b) { return $a['libelle_commune'] < $b['libelle_commune'] ? -1 : 1; });
```

sort abc... with **<** and ...cba with **>**

Comment: If you're using PHP 7 you can even even use the so called spaceship operator: `return $a['libelle_commune'] <=> $b['libelle_commune'];`. This sorts in the `abc` order. If you want that reversed, switch the `$a` and the `$b`. More info on that [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365346/what-is-the-spaceship-operator-in-php-7)