# I wonder for the meaning of this instruction

Tags: php

Can you explain to me the meaning of the following instruction :

```
? echo 2<=>1;
```

Indeed i do not understand how to interpret ? in the beginning.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: no I can't find ? before the echo

Comment: It's there. It's part of a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-are-the-php-operators-and-called-and-what-do-they-do).

Comment: is not a ternary operator : (Condition) ? (Statement1) : (Statement2). Because i don't have any condition before ?.

Comment: Do you have anything on the previous line? Logic can be broken down into multiple lines. In fact, it is a common practice for ternaries.

Comment: no nothing at all i only have this line on my whole .php file

Comment: That is not valid PHP. If you tried to run it, you'd get a syntax error.

Comment: OK, thanks. it's the same thing i'm saying. I got it on a test on codinGame. but the possible answers are (-1, 0, 1, 2, true).

Comment: It's possible that somebody only copied part of it and forgot to delete the `?`. The question is obviously about `<=>`.

Comment: It is a typo. Either developer has short tags enabled and cut off the `<` or it is in complete line. The answer to the question would be `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "?"`

Comment: Yes possible. thank you

Answer (score 1):

This might be symbolizing a ternary logic statement.  The '?' comes after the conditional statement followed by the "if" and "then" portion. In your case, (condition) ? 2<=>1;  The '<=>' is known as a **Spaceship Operator** [Documentation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365346/what-is-the-spaceship-operator-in-php-7).  2<=>1 evaluates to 1 since 2 is greater than one and it's on the left side.  So your statement here will echo (or print to the console) "1" if the condition is true.  Hoped this helped!!!

Comment: what is the condition according to you. there is only this line on all my code. so I do not see the two points which are required in the syntax